# How can I solve a problem of transcribing a long audio file into a text file using Google's speech-on-Text API?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

After recording an audio file in the cloud storage bucket (audio.wav), a Python code was applied to transcribe this file (audio.wav) into a "Resultado.text" file. However, although the transcription is perfect, only the first 6 lines and the last are transcribed. I tried to partition the original audio file into 10 parts, to transcribe smaller files, but the partitioned files recorded in the cloud storage bucket are empty, consequently preventing any transcription.

Initially I thought that because the original file was very long, this would be the cause of the transcription truncation, presenting only 6 initial and last lines. Then I looked for partitioning in an attempt to reduce the audio file to be transcribed. But since these partitionings resulted in empty recorded files in the bucket, I would like to have an alternative to either go back to using the original long file and see if there is any resource to get the full transcript without partitioning that file into smaller files, or resolve the issue. This is why the partitioned files are empty inside the cloud storage bucket.